# How do I get multiple icons to launch different activities in one application?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an application with two activities and I'd like to be able to have two icons appear in the launcher, each launching the respective activity within the app.

Specifically, I want one icon to launch my main app, and another icon to launch my settings activity. Is this possible?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
    <activity android:label="MyApp" android:name=".MyApp">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".MyApp"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity android:label="Settings" android:name=".Settings">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".Settings"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This creates two launcher icons, but they both run my main app instead of the second icon running my settings app. I've tried just having the launcher category but then I don't get an icon so it looks like I need the main action as well.

Is this the right approach or should I be declaring two applications in the manifest instead?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

What you need to do is have your settings activity launch in another task. You can do this by specifying its task affinity. This is done with the attribute `android:taskAffinity`. By default all activities share the same task affinity that defaults to main package specified in the manifest. On your settings activity you can specify `android:taskAffinity="your.own.package.SettingsTask"` to have the settings activity launch in its own task.

[Extra documentation.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: I don't see why this should require another task?? It works fine within a single task and separate tasks might create other problems.

Comment: Didn't work on me. Seems `taskAffinity` does not work without starting that `Activity` with flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Comment: @Qberticus It did not work for me. Only one Activity was constantly launched - the one defined at the top of the manifest.

Comment: perfect article: https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2012/06/04/create-application-with-multiple-entry-point-activities/

Answer (score 8):

You're definitely going in the right direction. This is what I have (truncated, because I have all of my activities in the list while I'm devving for fast access):

```
<activity android:name=".DeckDrill"
          android:label="DeckDrill">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".DeckList"
          android:label="DeckList">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I think what may be happening is interference from your action elements which specify the name of your class. I'm pretty sure that actions and categories need to refer to constants. I don't know how that would result in what you're seeing, but you could try removing them. Other than that, you pretty much have what I have.