# Installing one apk with two different entry point

Tags: android

In my application it contain activity A,B,C,D. Now, I want to enter in to my application with two different entry point. That means i want to enter from activity A as well as activity C. If I give intent filter like:

```
<intent-filter>                                                 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"      
<intent-filter>
```

for both activity A and C two icons will create in application launcher,but both are work same
that means if I click any icon it start from beginning, but my requirement is one icon as to start from beginning(Activity A) and other from Activity C.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270409/how-do-i-get-multiple-icons-to-launch-different-activities-in-one-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a preliminary Activity run as your main entry point which does nothing except decide which Activity to load, then loads it.  The Activity can simply read a preference, for example, of which entry point to run, then will load the corresponding activity.

You can also make the Activity run without displaying a screen with the following property in your manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
```

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable response, but i found out the solution. just by setting attributes like this...:)                                                                                  >android:taskAffinity="string1" for activity A and                                              >android:taskAffinity="string2" for activity C