# android) can i set a default activity that runs right after installing

Tags: android, android-activity, installation

in my app, there is two activity and i want to make activity1 to the starting activity after installation.
But now the RUN button (is showed right after packgae installing) is disabled.

below is the manifest file. thanks.

```
<activity ...1>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity ...2>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

> android) can i set a default activity that runs right after installing

No activity "runs right after installing". The user has to launch it from the launcher.

> below is the manifest file

No, it is not. That is not even valid XML.

Also, note that your third `<intent-filter>` is invalid. Not only are you missing any category (you need at least `DEFAULT` for activities), but `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` are not activity actions.

I am going to take a guess that you really mean to ask: "I have two activities, both described as ACTION_MAIN/CATEGORY_LAUNCHER, and now the Run button does not work -- what can I do?" The answer would be "either remove the ACTION_MAIN/CATEGORY_LAUNCHER `<intent-filter>` from one of them, or mark one of the two as disabled ([`android:enabled="false"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#enabled)) and enable it later on using `PackageManager`."

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the second:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

You shouldn't have 2 activities flagged as the MAIN and LAUNCHER activity.

Try removing it within activity2.

Check out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html the intentfilter s are discussed.

Comment: Really stupid answer, for example, i need to have two icons in my android dashboard, and i have the same problem with installation process, so what should I do?

Comment: What a stupid comment as well. Doesn't help to be polite even though you disagree ;-) Alas you're right.
Look at this SO question - this seems to answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270409/how-do-i-get-multiple-icons-to-launch-different-activities-in-one-application
I don't suppose you need 2 different icons to launch the same activity?