# How to assign visually different launch icons for different Android activities

Tags: android, android-activity, icons, launcher

After following successfully the method to set multiple LAUNCHER activities (as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270783/978329) using the *taskAffinity* attribute, I ended up with having separated icons, one for each Activity.

My problem is that all these icons look the same, based on the parent application icon.

I am looking for a way to assign a different visual icon for each LAUNCHER activity 
(e.g. one red icon, one green icon, one blue icon etc.) so the difference will not be only by the label, but also by the graphics.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In each `activity` element of your manifest add the `android:icon` attribute and assign it to a drawable. For example `<activity ... android:icon="@drawable/icon_x"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
android:icon="@drawable/my_activity_icon"
```

in each activity defined as launcher.

Comment: too bad your answer was a minute difference from Dan S answers :)