# I want to combine two apk file to form one and register both in one manifest. (android)

Tags: android, performance, security, android-layout

I want to combine two apk file to form one and register both in one manifest.
I have two .apk files, one is host application and second is advertisement...i want to combine it and want to run in different sandbox providing different uid, it may require additional library and need to create different installer to recognise modified apk file

Comment: Do you have the source code of both .apk ?

Comment: you can put one apk inside the assets folder of the other apk. You will need to offload that to external storage and prompt the user to install it though. Also, they need to have allowed "unknown sources" in app settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the souce code, probably, you could try this way out where you need to combine manifests for both the projects.

[Bundle two apk into a single apk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149805/bundle-two-apk-into-a-single-apk)