# Creating single apk from two apks/modules

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

I have an application which is both for mobile/tablet and tv. As of I am using leanback for the tv, this project consist of 3 modules. First one (library) contains all the classes which are common for both tv and mobile/tablet module, then I have tv and mobile/tablet module which in build generates two separate apks. One is for mobile/tablet and one is for tv. 
I am building a module which would contain both modules so I can generate a single apk. I was able to merge gradle build into one. But, I am using different themes for both apks. That is defined in the `<application>` in the manifest. Is there a way to determine or branch the build so that the app knows which theme to use without writing algorithm of display metrics ec. ?
Both themes are `AppTheme`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Leanback">
```

Would it be possible to provide values-tv for an example? So i don't have to do a complete refactor or where ever is this theme used to do if/else statement?

Any one have experience with merging two modules without making one of them a library?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149805/bundle-two-apk-into-a-single-apk) thread looks interesting, but this theme thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is right. Just use the resource specifier and add your second theme to the folder e.g. values-television. Your theme should extend a base theme so you do not struggle with naming issues. More information about resource configs can be found here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: Funny, I was reading that doc, but I did not notice that I can put `values-television`. I tried `values-tv` before. Thank you reminding me.