# Change theme depending on the activity?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

i need to have the application with two or more styles (i have now just two, but in the future will be at least ten), i have the style part resolved.
but the thing is the manifest, i need to launch the same activity, but with a different theme associated.

```
<activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/DefaultTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name_mc"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MCTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

well the thing is that i get a duplicated error.
Ok, i get that i can't have the same activity twice (at least that is the exception i get).

is there a workaround for this?
i do need the two launchers.

regards.

Comment: Could you please post the logcat error message you are getting?

Comment: it doesnt start at all.

Comment: So, you want to launch your activity with one of the several themes you have defined? If that's the issue, you can set the theme in `onCreate()`.

Comment: i get this compile exception.
Error:(76, 9) Element activity#com.example.StartActivity at AndroidManifest.xml:76:9 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:62:9

Comment: no, my major concern is that i need n icons to start the same activity but with different name (and parameters).

Answer (score 1):

One work around, if your activity is named StartActivity, then you can make StartActivityWithTheme1 extends StartActivity, StartActivityWithTheme2 extends StartActivity, etc. So you have all your logic in StartActivity.

Also if you want more than one launcher activity then read this SO: [Two launcher activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927315/two-launcher-activities)

Comment: yeah i tough that, but maybe there is a better way to do this.
anyway thanks i guess i will to this.

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can set the theme programatically.use this method-http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#setTheme%28int%29

To set the theme dynamically at runtime, call setTheme() in your activity's onCreate() method, before calling setContentView().