# Distribute and track multiple Android Apps

Tags: android, apk

How can one distribute (install and run) multiple android apps (APKs) through a single application? The objective is that the user should download a single app once, and multiple apps should be launched from within this app (similar to a launcher).

There is also a need to provide role-based access for users to applications within the main application, and track statistics such as number of downloads, user trends etc. Is there any framework available to do this?

Comment: 'How can one distribute (install and run) multiple android apps (APKs) through a single application?' != 'The objective is that the user should download a single app once, and multiple apps should be launched from within this app (similar to a launcher).'. Multiple APK's give separate applications.

Comment: Agreed, the requirement is that there are different types of users for this application and each one needs to be granted access to a separate set of apps (based on functional role). What would be the way to do that?

Comment: In one app: multiple launcher activities.

Answer (score -1):

You can add more main intents to the same APK and launch different activities [Two launcher activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927315/two-launcher-activities)