# How can i make two activities to one file?

Tags: java, android

I made two activities in Android Studio. One of them is an empty activity the other is a Basic activity. My Problem now is that if I run the app my Smartphone Shows me two files. How can I make this into one file?

[[image]]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two launcher activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927315/two-launcher-activities)

Answer (score 1):

It seems both of your activities have the android.intent.category.LAUNCHER

```
    <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```