# Two LEANBACK_LAUNCHER activities

Tags: android, android-tv

Trying to have two launcher activities, but only one is visible. Is it `AndroidTV` limitation that only one launcher icon is possible?

```xml
<application>
    <activity android:name="com.hello.MainActvity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.hello.DebugSettings">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927315/two-launcher-activities

Comment: Did you fund an answer for that? Is it not possible to have more than one?

Comment: Nope, apparently it's not possible.