# A second home screen button to open a secondary activity?

Tags: android, file, widget, homescreen

I made an image viewer `MyImageViewer`, and I had to build a filemanager for it, called `MyFileManager`, as a class. I open `MyFileManager` from `MyImageViewer` through Intents perfectly.

It turns out that now I like `MyFileManager` more than the actual file manager that came with my Android (that is tooooo slow and tooooo limited). So I want to add a second launcher button to the Home Screen for `MyFileManager` class, besides the one I already have for `MyImageViewer`.

Is there an easy way to do this, besides using widgets? In general widgets keep 'listening' to triggers, and hence consume battery and resources. I just want a simple button to launch my `MyFileManager`.

If widgets are the only solution, do you have a link/code to implement a very lightweight widget to do what I want? Or is this lightweight enough: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/modal-dialog-popup-from-android-widget-example.html

Thanks!!
L.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927315/two-launcher-activities

Comment: Perfect! This is extremely simple to do. Just to post a more direct link to the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270409/how-do-i-get-multiple-icons-to-launch-different-activities-in-one-application/3270783#3270783

Comment: Glad you solved your problem :)