# Pack few applications to one: Android

Tags: android

I have a requirement to create a single apk with link to three independent android applications is there any way to achieve the same via multiple  apks

I have tried creating library projects for each app  but then  each project itself requires some another  library so that gives error

Comment: So, all three applications should be installed with single apk ?

Comment: or better app should internally maintain this

Comment: why do you want to have 3 different applications? there can be other solutions to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is this :

```
<activity android:label="MyApp" android:name=".MyApp">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>


<activity android:label="Settings" android:name=".Settings">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This'll add two launcher icons which'll let you open two separate activities of the app. Similarly, add the third one.

Check out this question : [How do I get multiple icons to launch different activities in one application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270409/how-do-i-get-multiple-icons-to-launch-different-activities-in-one-application)

Answer (score 0):

> three independent android applications

If I am interpreting your wording correctly, and you mean that you want 3 APKs that are usually all on their own together in one APK, then **this is not possible**. This means that a modular Android application (a common appliance of such functionality) is also not possible.

On the other hand it is possible to have multiple `Activities` show up in the launcher by adding this `intent-filter` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` to the `Activities` you want to have visible:

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```